# java print screening

Tags: java, image, awt, screenshot, awtrobot

now what i've got is this but at the moment it takes the screenshot before the string is actually there causing the screenshot to be taken far too early

```
        if(string_75_.contains("You have defeated ")) {
            takeScreenshot(true);
        }
```

here is my whole printscreen routine

```
  static boolean takeScreenshot(boolean verbose){
    try{
      File file = getEmptyFile();
      Wait(50);
      ImageIO.write(getImage(), "png", file);
      if (verbose) {
        System.out.println("Screenshot saved as " + file.getName() + ".");  
      }
      return true;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      if (verbose)
        System.out.print("Error saving screenshot.");
    }
    return false;
  }
 private static BufferedImage getImage() throws IOException {
      try {
          Robot robot = new Robot();
          Wait(120);
          robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
          robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
          robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
          robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
          BufferedImage bufferedImage = (BufferedImage)getClipboard();
          return bufferedImage;
    } catch (AWTException e) {
         BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(765,503 + 11, 1);
         return bufferedImage;
    }
 }
```

Now the main issue is that the waits cause my application to stop entireley but STILL doesn't manage to take the screenshot early... any help is thankfull

also is there a way to clear the clipboard? without my wait() it seems to return the last image that was taken because its all happening so quickly

thanks!

Comment: The problem is most likely in the `Wait(int)` method (which should be called `wait(int)`).  
For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: See also [`Robot.delay(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#delay%28int%29)

Comment: i had to re-create the wait() method to become static so it was usable, all my methods had to be static to be compatable with what i'm using it with

Comment: *"all my methods had to be static"*  That sounds like the design is completely messed up.  But more comments when I see an SSCCE.

Comment: thanks for that but i just tryed it and the same issue again with it not being static

Comment: I just noticed `Class245.method2261`  Wow! Can you possibly vague that up for us?

Comment: i'll just go over it and clean it all up... that's actually just a sendmessage method to the client